What is the difference in Mouse.OverrideCursor and Mouse.SetCursor
From reading the documentation, there doesn't seem to be any difference between Mouse.OverrideCursor and Mouse.SetCursor other than Mouse.SetCursor returns a bool. Is this really the only difference?
I've searched and can't find anything that addresses the difference.

SetCursor sets the cursor to a specific value, and OverrideCursor will override it with something else. Then you can set OverrideCursor to null and it will revert to whatever was set by SetCursor

See the Remarks on the SetCursor page:

...  So, if after setting the cursor the mouse pointer moves over an object which sets the cursor, the cursor will be changed again.
To force the mouse pointer to a specific Cursor and to force this Cursor on all elements, set the OverrideCursor property.

If you have an element in the visual tree that sets its own Cursor property, this will be "overridden" by OverrideCursor, but not by SetCursor(),

Thanks for the answer. That helps me get my head around it.
